# Get access to all files in "recent documents" folder

Tags: java

I want to get a list of all files recently open or created, i.e. all the files in the Windows "recent folder" .

I can't find any solutions, I tried `shgetfolderpath`, windows registry but nothing worked. How can I get access to all files in the recent folder using Java?

Comment: Can you put at least a little effort into writing your question? That you can't do that makes me wonder what you've tried to solve your actual problem?

Comment: what i want to do is get all the files listed in "my recent document" folder

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why can't you use complete sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in java :

```
    File file = new File("Windows/Recent/Folder/Path");

    if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
        for (File files : listFiles) {
            if(files.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(files.getAbsolutePath() + " - Directory");
            }else {
                System.out.println(files.getAbsolutePath() + " - File");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i want to get rectly opened files by user .so this are store in my recent documents.that is a windows special folder so i want to et its path so i can acess the files(shortcut) listed there

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, try this out:

```
import java.io.File;

public class ListFiles 
{

     public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

      // Directory path here
      String path = "F:\\Book"; // the directory you want to search

      String files;
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
      {
           if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
           {
               files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
               System.out.println(files);// with out printing you can add the  names of file in array 
            }
      }
    }
}
```